# Malloc in Constructor returning NULL when called via New

Tags: c++, constructor

I recently started learning c++(I already have an intermediate level of c). I understand, the idea behind constructors and how they work, but I don't understand why when I create a Packet object using new, the malloc in the constructor returns NULL/0x0 memory position. If I define a Packet object I have no problem with the malloc in the constructor. 
Here's the code, would appreciate any corrections in format/coding :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Packet
{
    public:
        unsigned int size_pck;
        char *packet_data;

    Packet(unsigned int size)
    {
        size_pck=size;
        char *packet_data=(char *)malloc(size);
    }

    ~Packet()
    {
        free(packet_data);
    }



};

int main (void)
{
    Packet *created_pck;
    created_pck=new Packet(4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're assigning the result of `malloc` to a local variable, not the member variable of the same name.

Comment: golden rule: make destructor virtual

Comment: @JacekCz What? No. No no no.

Comment: @AlanStokes Thanks I'm an idiot.

Comment: The more c++ stylish way would be `packet_data = new char[size];` and `delete[] packet_data`...

Comment: @JacekCz A virtual destructor may be useful in many cases, but (1) it’s not always the right answer, and (2) it is completely irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: I had debugging very long override of similar class. I agree, my comment is out of exact question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one, you're creating a local variable - not assigning to your member:

```
Packet(unsigned int size)
{
    size_pck=size;
    packet_data=(char *)malloc(size);
}
```

For another, there's already a handy way in C++ to keep a dynamically sized array of `char`s: `std::vector`:

```
class Packet {
    std::vector<char> packet_data;
public:
    Packet(unsigned int size)
    : packet_data(size)
    { }
};
```

This has the added benefit of not leaking memory when you copy your `Packet`. Or, alternatively, `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` with the extra size member, to avoid initializing the `char`s - if that matters.

Comment: Thanks I'm an Idiot, I can't believe I didn't notice the char* that shadowed the variable in the class.

Comment: @Mr.Branch the second part of the answer is also important. Look up the Rule of Five/Zero. It's an important guideline for writing classes in C++

Comment: I was just looking into the vector class thanks a lot, if you have any other tips please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the constructor, you need to change the code from

```
char *packet_data=(char *)malloc(size);
```

to

```
packet_data=(char *)malloc(size);
```

You are allocating memory for a local variable whereas you need to allocate memory for the class variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you're defining a local variable that shadows the packet_data member.  Remove the `char *`  in the constructor and it will work fine.